# Ubuntu - mirroring single distro, single platform of armbian

Tags: mirrors, arm64, apt-mirror

How to mirror only single distro, single platform on some device itself or local LAN?

Lets say some device / network needs to be self sufficient. I have found that minimal requirements are `Space needs: 500Gb (images), 100Gb (packages) and (optional) 3TB for archives` for https://github.com/armbian/mirror

This is done with:

```
rsync -av rsync://mirrors.dotsrc.org/armbian-dl
rsync -av rsync://mirrors.dotsrc.org/armbian-apt
```

Is it possible to make cleaner sync and download only lunar / arm64??
To be honest I have no clue about mirror structure, are files shared between platforms / releases and other relevant knowledge so I'm just guessing. Will I need some other data which is not on armbian mirror?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.